# Is there a way in Python to take a string and find the list it is associated with?

Tags: python

```
l1 = ["a","b","c"]
l2 = ["d","e","f"]

var1 = input("What list do you want to use? (l1 or l2)" 

print (var1)
output: l1
```

how do I make it so if the user types in l1 the output will be: `["a","b","c"]` ?

The closest example I have found is:

```
x='buffalo'    
exec("%s = %d" % (x,2))
```

Comment: The general answer here is "use a `dict` keyed by the strings you care about, don't use raw variable names".

Answer (score 3):

A dictionary would be a great solution here.

```
mapping = {
    "l1": ["a","b","c"],
    "l2": ["d","e","f"]
}

var1 = input("What list do you want to use? (l1 or l2)")

mapping[var1]  # this is the list.
```

If `var1` is not a key in the dictionary, though, the above code will raise a `KeyError`. You can check for this and print a useful error message with a `try-except` block.

```
try:
    my_list = mapping[var1]
except KeyError:
    print("unknown input: {}".format(var1))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if var1 == 'I1':
  print(I1)
elif var1 == 'I2':
  print(I2)
```

That's just a basic if/else.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to look at `eval`

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval

Sample code:

```
l1 = ["a","b","c"]
l2 = ["d","e","f"]

var1 = input("What list do you want to use? (l1 or l2)")

print (var1)

eval("print(" + var1 + ")")
```

Output:

```
What list do you want to use? (l1 or l2)l1
l1
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: Do not use `eval` on user input. It is a major security risk. A user could theoretically delete all of your files.

Comment: eval was the missing piece! Thank you. Sorry, still a noob here so they will not let me upvote your answer. It is indeed the correct one.

This is a soundboard, so I am not concerned about security, but thank you jakub